# JQuery : event.preventDefault()

Tags: jquery

In which condition we use JQuery : event.preventDefault(); ....
where it will be used ?

Comment: This is quite worth the read: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to prevent the default behaviour. For example when handling a form submit event, if you want to post with ajax and not have your page refresh, you would use `event.preventDefault()`.

```
$('#myform').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // ajax stuff...
});
```

Returning `false` from your function will usually have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks giving me ans....but i am confused :::: So is there any different between "return false" and ev.preventDefault(),so may i used "false"  instead of "preventDefault()"... yes? may i right or not ?

Comment: IMO event.preventDefault(); is better than return false;. If you use return false and there is an error the event will still fire which usually makes it harder to debug(If you navigate to a new page all the errorinfo is lost).

Answer (score 3):

```
function() {
  return false;
}

// IS EQUAL TO

function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

one other very good example is href

```
<a href="http://www.sometest.com" class="justtest">
test</a>
```

the following code will show an alert and takes the user to its default behavior which is href and `www.sometst.com`

```
$('.justtest').submit(function(ev) {
    alert("a href click");
});
```

if i use event.preventDefault , it will just show the alert and stops its default behavior.it doesn't take the user to `www.sometest.com`

```
$('.justtest').submit(function(ev) {
    alert("a href click");
    event.preventDefault();// this is better 
    // return faslse// return false will kill all the events so try to use preventDefault
});
```

got it from SO only

Returning false from jQuery event handlers is equivalent to calling both, `e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation.`

So the difference is that `preventDefault` will only prevent the default event action to occur, i.e. a page redirect on a link click, a form submission, etc. and return false will also stop the event flow.

see this also

http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/